# String concatenation does not work

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm trying to concatenate two strings and the result string is not concatenated at all. I don't know where is the problem. The line that is a problem is that line

```
tempString = tempString+ result;
```

Here is the full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <limits>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>
#include <numeric>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>


using namespace std;
#define  OTHER 3
#define  SQUARE 1
#define  RECTANGLE 2


static std::string accum(const std::string &s)
{
    string result = "";
    string tempString = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        int temp = i+1;
        if (i == 0)
        {

            result[i] += s[i];
            result[i] = toupper(result[i]);
            tempString = tempString+ result;
            tempString += "-";

        }
        else
        {
            if (i!=1)
            { 
            tempString += '-';
            }
            while (temp > 0)
            {
                tempString+=s[i];

                temp--;
            }

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tempString.size(); i++)
    {
        if (tempString[i] == '-')
        {
            tempString[i + 1] = toupper(tempString[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    return tempString;
}

int main() {

    string result = accum("abcd");
}
```

Comment: You can try to append the second string to the first one using `append()`

Comment: there is no reason for it not to work. why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Concatenating 2 `std:string`s using `+` works fine, but the result of concatenating 2 empty string is also an empty string.

Comment: BTW, that entire `accum` function could have been written using `std::accumulate`, all in one or two lines of code.

Comment: [Using std::accumulate](http://ideone.com/gT4JLu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:
`result[i] += s[i];`
to this:

```
result += s[i];
```